# Run rspec scripts against virtualbox

Tags: rspec, virtualbox, watir, watir-webdriver

I would like to run my rspec tests against a VirtualBox that is running Windows.  I would like to use this as a sandbox before pushing the tests to our master repo. I am not sure were to begin.  I haven't been able to find anything on google or here.

Any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up [VirtualBox](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-8-in-Virtual-Box) yet?  You'll need a Windows .iso, and then you'll have to set up the VM with ruby and required gems.  From there, you should be able run your tests locally before committing to your repo.

Comment: I have Virtualbox and windows iso installed.  I would like to execute the tests from my Mac.  Not sure how to setup that up.

Comment: I've never had to do it, but it looks like you can [control VirtualBox from the command line of your host operating system](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html).